# cmake link two libraries +

Tags: c, cmake

I'm trying to link two libraries. One depends on the other. They are both on the same level. I tried to follow the documentation for my version but when I compile it the include with <> doesn't work.

The dependency

```
include_directories(headers)

add_library(log SHARED log.c)
target_compile_definitions(log PUBLIC log)
```

The dependent

```
include_directories(headers)

add_library(window OBJECT dialog.c ncurses_add.c window.c)
target_compile_definitions(window PUBLIC OBJ)
target_link_libraries(window log)
```

Could anyone help me understand why is that ? Thanks

Comment: Add `target_include_directories(log PUBLIC headers)` to the first cmake file.

Comment: So for the dependency, right ? It adds the header files to the path ?

Comment: _Never_ use `include_directories`. Forget it exists. Only use target commands and avoid directory commands like the plague.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `target_include_directories(log INTERFACE headers)` or `target_include_directories(log PUBLIC headers)` to the `log` CMakeLists.txt.

From the [target_include_directories manual](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html):

> PUBLIC and INTERFACE items will populate the INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES property of <target>

From the [INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES manual](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES.html#prop_tgt:INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES):

> List of public include directories requirements for a library. Targets may populate this property to publish the include directories required to compile against the headers for the target

What that means is that any dependent targets will get the include paths of the dependency added to their build commands.

Comment: +1 but this answer would be better if it included a suggestion to avoid `include_directories` for its redundancy with this solution and general inferiority